# wpf datagrid combo box binding to database

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I want my DataGrid have ComboBox with default value for example I have a column for Genre:

1. Action
2. Drama
3. Comedy

I Want ComboBox Show those data and then select the item in database (for example in database Genre is Drama.

1. I use WPF Net 6 with EF Sqlite for manage Database.
2. in Database Class I set Genre as string.
3. DataGrid of other Column I use Something like this:

   ```
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding Path=ID,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
   ```
4. in Code Behind: `DgTest.ItemsSource=db.Test.ToList();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i fix my problem. same as Firo but in simple way.

My Model for Genre:

```
public int ID {get; set;}
public string? Title {get; set;}
```

my Repository:

```
Create A list of Genre and then Return it
```

My View-Model

```
public ObservableCollection<Genre> AllGenreList => new (_repository.GetAllGenre())
private Genre _genre;
public Genre SelectedGenre{get=> _genre; set{ _genre=value; ONotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Genre);}
```

and then Bind AllGenreList to ComboBox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllGenreList }" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGenre}"/>
```

this is how i fix my problem. hope solve some one else problem.

Answer (score 0):

i would strongly advise to use [MVVM pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/mvvm) as it is a best practice for WPF applications. It could look like this

Boilerplate

```
public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    protected virtual void SetValue<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}

public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute ?? DefaultCanExecute;
    }

    private bool DefaultCanExecute() => true;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _execute();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute();
    }
}

public class DelegateCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<T> _execute;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
    public DelegateCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute));

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute ?? DefaultCanExecute;
    }

    private bool DefaultCanExecute(T _) => true;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(T parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(T parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        Execute((T)parameter);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class MoviesViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _dbContext;

    private Task _runningQuery;
    private CancellationTokenSource _runningQueryCancellation;
    private const int _pageSize = 100;

    public MoviesViewModel()
    {
        _dbContext = new MyDbContext();

        _dbContext.Movies.Add(new Movie { Name = "foo", Genre = "Genre1" });
        _dbContext.Movies.Add(new Movie { Name = "bar", Genre = "Genre1" });
        _dbContext.Movies.Add(new Movie { Name = "baz", Genre = "Genre2" });
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        ReloadCommand = new DelegateCommand(ReloadMovies);
        NextPageCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => Page++, () => ((Page + 1) * _pageSize) < _movieCount);
        PreviousPageCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => Page--, () => Page > 0);
        _runningQuery = LoadGenresAndCount();
    }

    private async Task LoadGenresAndCount()
    {
        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            var genres = await _dbContext.Movies.Select(m => m.Genre).Distinct().OrderBy(g => g).ToListAsync();
            genres.Insert(0, null);   // add option for no Genre selected
            Genres = genres;
            MovieCount = await _dbContext.Movies.CountAsync();
            ReloadMovies();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error = $"Error while loading {ex}";
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand ReloadCommand { get; }
    public DelegateCommand NextPageCommand { get; }
    public DelegateCommand PreviousPageCommand { get; }

    // properties use SetValue to tell the view to update itself when the value changes
    private bool _isBusy;
    public bool IsBusy { get { return _isBusy; } set { SetValue(ref _isBusy, value); } }

    private string _error;
    public string Error { get { return _error; } private set { SetValue(ref _error, value); } }

    private IEnumerable<string> _genres;
    public IEnumerable<string> Genres { get => _genres; private set => SetValue(ref _genres, value); }

    private string _selectedGenre;
    public string SelectedGenre
    {
        get { return _selectedGenre; }
        set { SetValue(ref _selectedGenre, value); ReloadMovies(); }
    }

    private int _movieCount;
    public int MovieCount { get => _movieCount; private set => SetValue(ref _movieCount, value); }

    private IEnumerable<Movie> _movies;
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Movies { get => _movies; private set => SetValue(ref _movies, value); }

    private int _page;
    public int Page
    {
        get { return _page; }
        private set
        {
            SetValue(ref _page, value);
            NextPageCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            PreviousPageCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            ReloadMovies();
        }
    }

    private void ReloadMovies()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        Error = null;
        // cancel the running query because the filters have changed
        _runningQueryCancellation?.Cancel();
        _runningQueryCancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
        
        // having selectedGenre as parameter so it doesn't change for the asynchron operation
        _runningQuery = ReloadMoviesAsync(_runningQuery, SelectedGenre, _runningQueryCancellation.Token);
    }
    private async Task ReloadMoviesAsync(Task queryBefore, string selectedGenre, CancellationToken token)
    {
        // wait for running query to finish to prevent parallel access to the context which is not thread safe
        if (queryBefore != null)
            await queryBefore;
        try
        {
            IQueryable<Movie> query = _dbContext.Movies;
            if (selectedGenre != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(m => m.Genre == selectedGenre);
            }
            Movies = await query
                .OrderBy(m => m.Name)                           // usefull and nessesary for skip take
                .Skip(_page * _pageSize).Take(_pageSize)        // only load items of the page
                .AsNoTracking()                                 // tell ef to not track changes
                .ToListAsync(token);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error = $"Error while loading {ex}";
        }
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="SomeApplication.MoviesView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SomeApplication"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Movies" Height="450" Width="800">
    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <local:MoviesViewModel/>
    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TrueToVisible"/>
    </FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <!--header-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Content="Reload" Command="{Binding ReloadCommand}"/>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Genres}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGenre}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <!--footer-->
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <TextBlock Text="Page"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Page}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Total Movies" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MovieCount}"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding PreviousPageCommand}" Content="&lt;" Margin="5"/>
            <Button Command="{Binding NextPageCommand}" Content="&gt;" Margin="5"/>
        
            <!--busy Indicator-->
            <TextBlock Text="Loading..." Visibility="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={StaticResource TrueToVisible}}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Movies}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Genre" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Genre}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Genres, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.Style>
                <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Error}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Style>
        </DataGrid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Error}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Error}" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I recently know about mvvm and trying to learn it. I will test it. But i just want to you know that i want combobox in datagrid not outside of it. I want use datagridcombobox or datagridtemplate with combobox inside it. So i can easily change data in datagrid (using roweditending). So this code is that i want?

Comment: @Saman added the  binding of the column

Comment: i am trying to test. those code. in MyDbContext . i can't find the code? so there is no diffrent in MVVM way anc Code Behind way? i know what is MyDbContext. just want to know that in MVVM way and in Code Behind Way is diffrent or not. if is diffrent can you give that code too?

Comment: The code uses the Datacontext which is the intended way in WPF. It should be the same with code behind setting the collection of the datagrid. However the relativesource only works if the object with the available Genres is the datacontext of the datagrid